# J console history on ARM

Tags: command-line-interface, j

On my ARM Chromebook, `jconsole` interprets my arrows strangely. I expect up and down to cycle through previous/next entries in the history of commands I've typed, but instead I get symbols.

<kbd>key</kbd> → `resulting console display`:

<kbd>up</kbd> → `^[[A`

<kbd>down</kbd> → `^[[B`

<kbd>right</kbd> → `^[[C`

<kbd>left</kbd> → `^[[D`

## J version

**Note: I get the same result on J803**

```
   JVERSION
Engine: j701/2011-02-23/15:25
Library: 8.02.12
Platform: Linux 32
Installer: J802 install
InstallPath: /home/lex/j802
```

## OS/platform

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Mon Nov 17 22:09:22 PST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 running inside a chroot on Chrome OS, and the same behavior occurs with `xterm`, XFCE's `Terminal` and Chrome OS's `hterm`.

Other command line interpreters (e.g. Python, Node) work normally, so I assume it's unique to the J console app.

Comment: Those look to be the standard codes for the arrow keys; many GNU-targeted console-type-things will be compiled to use the `readline` library to do something in response to them - presumably your copy of `jconsole` isn't.

Comment: thanks, now I have a place to start looking.

Comment: @Notlikethat I think you were spot-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source](http://www.jsoftware.com/source.htm) readme, I found the following line:

```
jconfig as distributed sets 32bit and no line recall. Edit jconfig as required.
```

...And in the corresponding `jconfig`:

```
# remove # from next 2 lines to enable readline                                                                                            
# readline=1                                                                                                                               
# LIBREADLINE=" -lreadline "
```

So it appears that my copy has `readline` disabled, as suggested in the comments.

However, I just learned that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> will display the previously entered line, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> will display the next, etc. So training one's fingers can be a substitute for rebuilding the app.

## Update

The current stable (J803) version for ARM has readline support, apparently. My arrow keys work normally. Neat.